# Eigen use of diagonal matrix

Tags: c++, performance, eigen

Using Eigen, I have a Matrix3Xd (3 rows, n columns). I would like to get the squared norm of all columns

to be clearer, lets say I have

```
Matrix3Xd a =
1    3    2    1
2    1    1    4
```

I would like to get the squared norm of each column

```
squaredNorms =
5    10    5    17
```

I wanted to take advantage of matrix computation instead of going through a for loop doing the computation myself.

What I though of was

```
squaredNorms = (A.transpose() * A).diagonal()
```

This works, but I am afraid of performance issues: `A.transpose() * A` will be a nxn matrix (potentially million of elements), when I only need the diagonal.

Is Eigen clever enough to compute only the coefficients I need?
What would be the most efficient way to achieve squareNorm computation on each column?

Comment: How about [element-wise multiplication](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html#title4) (using [`.array()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html#title6)) followed by partial reduction [`.colwise()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html#title5) [`.sum()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The case of `(A.transpose() * A).diagonal()` is explicitly handled by Eigen to enforce lazy evaluation of the product expression nested in a diagonal-view. Therefore, only the `n` required diagonal coefficients will be computed.

That said, it's simpler to call `A.colwise().squaredNorm()` as well noted by Eric.

Comment: Will this change if I enable MKL support for Eigen? It seems MKL gemm() would interrupt the lazy evaluation.

Comment: nope because here the shortcut is applied before calling gemm-like routines (either Eigen's built-in or whatever blas backend)

Comment: Thanks for both the explaination on lazy eval and the simpler approach using colwise! just what I needed

Comment: In 2023, it appears like these two approaches produce the same assembly output, so the best option is probably whichever is easier for you to read. https://godbolt.org/z/fd3h14f63

Answer (score 4):

This will do what you want.

```
squaredNorms = A.colwise().squaredNorm();
```

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html

> Eigen provides several reduction methods such as: minCoeff() , maxCoeff() , sum() , prod() , trace() *, norm() *, squaredNorm() *, all() , and any() . All reduction operations can be done matrix-wise, column-wise or row-wise .